# Laravel installation error in PHP 5.5

Tags: laravel-4, composer-php

I am trying to install laravel in local machine. But got some error. I am using wamp, PHP version is 5.5.12 . 
Please have a look at the screenshot below.
[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do `php --version` to see if the PHP executable used by the cmd is the same as the one used by wamp. It probably isn't. When installing a new PHP release, you also have to change your PATH environment variable to point to the new php executable.

Comment: Yes, you are right. PHP version is 5.3.13 , which is my earlier version. But my wamp PHP version is  5.5.12 ,  How can i upgrade this?
Thanks

Comment: Thanks lot.. Finally able to install Laravel :)